# Laravel Storage::get cannot find file, returns 404

Tags: php, laravel, file, path, storage

After uploading a document successfully like this:

```
$documentUploaded = $company->addMedia($file)->toMediaCollection();
```

When I try to fetch the document using storage:

```
Storage::get($documentUploaded->getPath());
```

I get the following error:

> League\Flysystem\FileNotFoundException(code: 0): File not found at
>   path:
>   C:/wamp/www/my-app/storage/app/public/69/THIS-WILL-BE-ENCRYPTED.docx
>   at
>   C:\wamp\www\my-app\vendor\league\flysystem\src\Filesystem.php:388)
>   [stacktrace]

When I try to dump the file path:

```
dd($documentUploaded->getPath());
```

I get this:

`C:\wamp\www\my-app\storage\app\public/69/THIS-WILL-BE-ENCRYPTED.docx`

When I check in both `storage` and `public` directories I can see the file there.

I already created a symlink between the public and storage directories with `php artisan storage:link` so I don't know what's going on here?

Comment: This links might be useful. [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438008/different-behaviours-of-treating-backslash-in-the-url-by-firefox-and-chrome), [link 2](https://pc.net/helpcenter/answers/backslash_vs_forward_slash)

Comment: I think its a matter of slash. That's why you are getting not found error.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is I am not manually creating the path, so the slashes are generated by `getPath()`

Comment: try static address for testing like this:- `Storage::get(C:\wamp\www\my-app\storage\app\public\69\THIS-WILL-BE-ENCRYPTED.docx);` and see if it is able to find file.. do acknowledge me of the outcome.

Comment: I get exactly the same thing: `File not found at path: C:/wamp/www/my-app/storage/app/public/69/THIS-WILL-BE-ENCRYPTED.docx`

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome v66.0.3359.181. I am using Laravel 5.6 and media library v7

Comment: can you download firefox and see if it works there? this slash issue is frequent on chrome and IE. firefox handles it.

Comment: Just tried that. Exact same thing. It's not a browser issue, its something to do with the way the Laravel storage symlink works.

Comment: For the get method, the file path should be specified relative to the "root" location configured for the disk.

Comment: @JCPHPDev The root location for my `public` disk is `'root' => storage_path('app/public'),`

Comment: try this Storage::get('public/69/THIS-WILL-BE-ENCRYPTED.docx');

Comment: @SakibAbrar It returns nothing at all, when I try `dd(Storage::disk('public')->exists('public/69/THIS-WILL-BE-ENCRYPTED.docx'));` it returns false

Comment: try dd(Storage::disk('local')->exists('public/69/THIS-WILL-BE-ENCRYPTED.docx'));

Comment: Okay that returns true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path should be relative to the 'project_name/storage/app' folder. So you have to do this

```
Storage::get('public/69/THIS-WILL-BE-ENCRYPTED.docx');
```

Comment: Is there any way I can easily get `69` (folder name) from `$documentUploaded->getPath()`?