# How to store a special character in a string in R

Tags: r, string, special-characters

I am trying to store the special escape character `\` in R as part of a string.

```
x = "abcd\efg"

# Error: '\e' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""abcd\e"

x = "abcd\\efg"

# Works
```

The problem is that `x` is actually a password that I am passing as part of an API web call so I need to find a way for the string to store a literal single slash in order for this to work.

Example using the ignoring literal command:

```
> x = r"(abcd\efg)"

> y = "https://url?password="

> paste(x, y, sep = "")
[1] "abcd\\efg123"

> # What I need is for it to return
[1] "abcd\efg123"

> z = paste(y, x, sep = "")

> z
[1] "https://url?password=abcd\\efg"

> cat(z)
https://url?password=abcd\efg
```

When I pass `z` as part of the API command I get "bad credentials" message because it's sending `\\` as part of the string. `cat` returns it to the console correctly, but it appears to not be sending it the same way it's printing it back.

Comment: If you run `x = "abcd\\efg"` then `cat(x)` you'll see here is only one slash in there. The `cat()` will not escape "special" characters. And `nchar(x)` returns 8. You just need to escape the slash when typing a string literal value in R code. It should work just fine.

Comment: That seems like it only works for returning the string to the console. I ultimately need to pass x on to part of another string.

Comment: It will be fine. The point is there is just one real slash in that string despite the fact that R escapes the special value only when `print()`ing the value.If this is causing a problem somewhere, show the code thats actually giving you an error.

Comment: I updated with code, i need to send x3 as part of a url call and I have been storing it like this. I works for everything except for passwords with that escape character

Comment: Only use `cat()` to print the value, not to combine it with other values. To concatenate strings, use `paste()`. For example: `x3 = paste(x2, y); cat(x3)`

Comment: Note that as of R 4.0, you can also use "special" strings that ignore escaping. `x4 = r"(abcd\efg)"` and if you do that you'll see `x2==x4` is TRUE

Comment: Have you tried passing `cat(x2, y)` directly by any chance (not x3)?

To concatenate, you should do paste0, not paste (It inserts a space by default).

Comment: Ive added an example using the `r"()"` command. I can see how you can get the correct result printed to the console, but i still do not see how the literal value is stored in the object

Comment: What you see print()ed to the condole is not the “true” value in the variable. If you want to see the true value, then you need to cat() the paste()ed value. All objects are transformed by the print() function in some way. Even a literal value is preceded by a [1] to show its part of a vector. That string isn’t actually in the vector. You are just misinterpreting the output. The variable contains the value you need and will work just fine when making an API call.

Comment: I added a little bit more in the edits. I understand what you are saying, but when i concatenate the string into another string and ship it off as part of the url then it seems to translate to a literal \\ and i get a bad credentials complaint.

Comment: @Jeston you are assuming this is the cause of your bad credentials, but it isn't. A single "\" printed to the R console appears as a "\\" in thr R console. It's not translating to a double "\\", which would appear as "\\\\" in the R console. Are you sure there is no other reason you are getting a bad credentials error?

Comment: Could you possibly need *additional* escapes for the API? I'd try `"https://url?password=abcd\\\\efg"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like everyone else in the comments said, the string appears to be handled correctly by R. I would assume it becomes a trouble somewhere else down the line. Either the API or the pass-matching software itself might be doing something with it.

As one example, the backslash will not work in most browsers if written verbatim, you would need to use `%5C` instead. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10438008/1953718) is one discussion about it.

So in your case - try replacing the backslash with something else, either `%5C` or, as @Roland mentioned in the comments, some extra back-slash symbols, like `\\\\` or `\\\` or `\\`. And then see if any of them work.

Answer (score 0):

The answers and comments contain the solution, but for completeness ill post an answer that matches my specific situation.

My package expects the user to supply a password. If there is a `\` in the password the command will fail as stated above. The solution seems to be to take care of it on the input rather than trying to alter the value once the user submits the password.

```
library(RobinHood)

# If the true password is: abc\def

# The following inputs will all work
rh <- RobinHood("username", pwd = r"(abc\def)")
rh <- RobinHood("username", pwd = "abc\\def")
rh <- RobinHood("username", pwd = "abc%5Cdef")
```